# Android create a preview image at a specific frame of video from an Url (on Internet)

Tags: android, android-studio, video, preview

I search a solution to create a preview image at a specific frame of video from an Url (on Internet) in Android Studio. I  tried to use MediaMetadataRetriever but it dont take urls as i want (my sample url is: http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: do you need a specefic frame or just a thumbnail?

Comment: I need an image (thumbnail) from a video with an url, at a specifique time ( as 10 seconds for exemple)

Comment: well I usually use ThumbnailUtils to get thumbnails from a file located on the device which goes something like this `Bitmap thum = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail(uri, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.FULL_SCREEN_KIND);` which will return a thumbnail in Bitmap. The problem is I dont know of the uri has to be a location on device but you can always try

Comment: and from an url not a file path like http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4, i tried this but how can i get the frame at 10 seconds ?